# Declare routing WEB API 2 using the Start Up class

Tags: url-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a new WEB API 2 project named as API TEST created. I am trying to enable the routing in my application and for that I am using the below code:-

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Regular Route",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

I have a home controller and in that controller I have a method as follows:-

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetStatus()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Now my solution explorer is as follows:-

[image: Solution Explorer]

Now when I try to call the controller method i get a 404 error.

Please advise.

Comment: Is your Startup Configuration method being called?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up routes in the config, why not use the Route and RoutePrefix attributes to set up your routes

```
[RoutePrefix("api/home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
   [Route("status")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetStatus()
   {
       return Ok();
   }
}
```

You would then be able to access that through the url api/home/status.